# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT when switching from Obj-c to Swift file

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I have changed from Obj-c to swift. However in my view controller identity inspector, only Obj-c files are available when I try to set the custom class.

Any ideas how to get the Swift files to appear?

Comment: thats pretty vague.. tells us what the error message says, where it breaks in debbugger and the code ;) who can help you without ANY information.

Comment: Are all breakpoints enabled? (It's odd that you'd simply get a SIGABRT without some debugging information.)

Comment: that said Ill risk a guess: given code is correct, the classname of your view controller might be wrong in the storyboard and thus you get a UIViewController and it will crash trying to set outlets :)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that my class was a subclass of UIViewController despite it being a UITableView. Changing this in the class worked.